# Django error when trying to edit an entry - Cannot resolve keyword 'count' into field

Tags: python, django, models

I am getting a FieldError when I try to edit certain models in the Django admin.

As far as I can tell, this started happening after I started using `.annotate()` in some of my `ModelAdmin` classes. The error shows up if I try to edit a Profile or a Photo. It also shows up if I try to edit a token (I am using Django REST Framework). What's confusing me though is why Token is also breaking; I have't touched that model at all. Here are the relevant models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, common_models.EditMixin, PermissionsMixin):
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=common_models.get_uploaded_file_path, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='staff account')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=common_models.get_uploaded_file_path, blank=True, null=True)
    gear = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class UserAction(models.Model):
    ACTION_CHOICES = (
        ('photo_click', 'Photo Click'),
        ('photo_imp', 'Photo Impression'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(account_models.User)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=ACTION_CHOICES)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class PhotoClassification(models.Model):
    CLASSIFICATION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('category', 'Category'),
        ('tag', 'Tag')
    )

    classification_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=CLASSIFICATION_TYPE_CHOICES, default='tag')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class PhotoFeed(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Photo(common_models.EditMixin):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(PhotoClassification, related_name='category')
    photo_feed = models.ManyToManyField(PhotoFeed, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(PhotoClassification, blank=True, related_name='tag')
    user = models.ForeignKey(account_models.User, blank=True, null=True)
    user_action = GenericRelation(UserAction)

    attribution_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=common_models.get_uploaded_file_path)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Here is one of the `ModelAdmin` classes that user `.annotate()`:

```
class PhotoClassificationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Categories and tags
    """
    list_display = ('name', 'classification_type', 'photo_count', 'public', 'id',)
    ordering = ('classification_type', 'name',)
    search_fields = ('name', 'classification_type', 'id',)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super(PhotoClassificationAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)\
            .annotate(photos_in_category=Count('category'), photos_in_tag=Count('tag'))

    def photo_count(self, obj):
        return obj.photos_in_category + obj.photos_in_tag

    photo_count.admin_order_field = 'photos'
    photo_count.short_description = 'Photos'
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/photo/photo/120/change/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 109, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 86, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 208, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 70, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 70, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 70, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 210, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 210, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 315, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 315, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1050, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1028, in render_value_in_context
    value = force_text(value)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 76, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(s)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 391, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 43, in __str__
    return self.as_widget()
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 101, in as_widget
    return force_text(widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs))
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py", line 307, in render
    'widget': self.widget.render(name, value, *args, **kwargs),
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 544, in render
    options = self.render_options([value])
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 567, in render_options
    for option_value, option_label in self.choices:
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1118, in __iter__
    for obj in queryset:
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 824, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 369, in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 47, in pre_sql_setup
    order_by = self.get_order_by()
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 293, in get_order_by
    field, self.query.get_meta(), default_order=asc))
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 553, in find_ordering_name
    field, targets, alias, joins, path, opts = self._setup_joins(pieces, opts, alias)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 586, in _setup_joins
    pieces, opts, alias)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1402, in setup_joins
    names, opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True)
  File "/home/martin/projects/aov3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1327, in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'count' into field. Choices are: attribution_name, category, created_at, id, image, location, modified_at, original_image_url, photo_data, photo_feed, public, tag, user, user_action, user_id
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @Alasdair I just added the traceback. My bad, I forgot to provide that.

Comment: It turns out that since I use `return super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).annotate(photos=Count('photo'))` in my `UserAdmin` class, it breaks the admins of models that have a foreign key to my `User` model. The solution is to override the `User` queryset in the other admins' `render_change_form()` and change the queryset:

`context['adminform'].form.fields['user'].queryset = models.User.objects.all()`

OR

add the foreign key field (`User' in my case), to `readonly_fields`.

Not sure if I messed something up or if this is a bug in Django.